# Acquire/Release VS Sequential Consistency in C++11？

Tags: c++, atomic, memory-barriers, memory-model, stdatomic

```
#include <thread>
#include <atomic>
#include <cassert>

std::atomic<bool> x = {false};
std::atomic<bool> y = {false};
std::atomic<int> z = {0};

void write_x()
{
    x.store(true, std::memory_order_release);
}

void write_y()
{
    y.store(true, std::memory_order_release);
}

void read_x_then_y()
{
    while (!x.load(std::memory_order_acquire))
        ;
    if (y.load(std::memory_order_acquire)) {
        ++z;
    }
}

void read_y_then_x()
{
    while (!y.load(std::memory_order_acquire))
        ;
    if (x.load(std::memory_order_acquire)) {
        ++z;
    }
}

int main()
{
    std::thread a(write_x);
    std::thread b(write_y);
    std::thread c(read_x_then_y);
    std::thread d(read_y_then_x);
    a.join(); b.join(); c.join(); d.join();
    assert(z.load() != 0);
}
```

If I relplace seq_cst to acquire/release in [cppreference's last example](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/memory_order),
can `assert(z.load() != 0)` be fail ?

- Seq_CST can prevent StoreLoad reorder, but the code hasn't.
- Acquire can prevent LoadLoad reorder.
- Release can prevent StoreStore reorder.

Comment: related, maybe duplicate: [Will two atomic writes to different locations in different threads always be seen in the same order by other threads?](//stackoverflow.com/a/50679223) - yes acq/rel allows IRIW reordering, unlike seq_cst.  Real HW that can make that happen in practice is rare, maybe just POWER.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the assert can fire.

The principal property that is *not* guaranteed by acquire / release is a single total order of modifications. It only guarantees that (the non-existent) previous actions of `a` and `b` are observed by `c` and `d` if they see `true` from the loads.

A (slightly contrived) example of this is on a multi-cpu (physical socket) system that isn't fully cache-coherant. Die 1 has core A running thread `a` and core C running thread `c`. Die 2 has core B running thread `b` and core D running thread `d`. The interconnect between the two sockets has a long latency when compared to a memory operation that hits on-die cache.

`a` and `b` run at the same wall clock time. C is on-die with A, so can see the store to `x` immediately, but the interconnect delays it's observation of the store to `y`, so it sees the old value. Similarly D is on-die with B, so it sees the store to `y`, but misses the store to `x`.

Whereas if you have sequential consistency, some co-ordination is required to enforce a total order, such as "C and D are blocked while the interconnect syncs the caches".

Comment: That's not how real multi-socket systems work. In real life they're always cache-coherent (or else we don't run std::threads across them); a new value can't become visible at all to other physical cores (within one package or on a different socket) until the writing core has exclusive ownership of the cache line (MESI Modified state), invalidating all stale copies *before* committing the store.

Comment: The actual mechanism for IRIW reordering on POWER is similar to what you described, but the some-threads-see-it-early mechanism (before it becomes *globally* visible by committing to L1d cache) is store-forwarding between logical cores of an SMT physical core (like hyperthreading). 
 [Will two atomic writes to different locations in different threads always be seen in the same order by other threads?](//stackoverflow.com/a/50679223).  seq_cst prevents this with a combination of barriers that I assume makes sure loads aren't forwarded from the store buffer at all; extra barrier before SC loads

Comment: I think this answer can benefit from adding a simple "Yes, the assert can fire."

Comment: @PeterCordes _seq_cst prevents this with a combination of barriers that I assume makes sure loads aren't forwarded from the store buffer at all; extra barrier before SC loads_; I believe a (full/sync/hwsync) barrier _between_ SC loads works as well, see [here](https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~pes20/ppc-supplemental/test7.pdf#page=22) (IRIW+dmbs/syncs litmus test). A C++11 compiler could insert "trailing fences", where a fence is placed _after_ the first load. The _first_ load could still be forwarded from the store buffer, but the second load executes only after the first load is globally visible.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it is possible that `z.load() == 0` in your code if you use `acquire`/`release` order as you've done. There is no happens-before relationship between the independent writes to `x` and `y`. It's not a coincidence cppreference used that example specifically to illustrate a case where acquire/release isn't sufficient.

This is sometimes call the IRIW (independent reads of independent writes), and tended to be glossed over in some hardware ordering models. In particular, a memory model defined only in terms of the possible load-load, load-store, store-store, etc, reorderings doens't say anything either way really about IRIW. In the x86 memory model IRIW reordering is disallowed because of a clause that explains that stores have a total order and all processors view stores in this same order.

I'm not aware if any CPUs in common use admit the IRIW reordering when the barriers and/or instructions needed for acquire and release are used, but I wouldn't be surprised if some do.

Comment: It's probably glossed over because the strongest fences that prevent any re-ordering (incl. #SL) usually enforce seq/cst.

Comment: @LWimsey Yeah, but for example on Intel even without fences you get consistent IRIW order, but it took a long time for them to actually document and guarantee it. They started out instead with this "causal consistency" statement but it was pretty useless and eventually after pointing pointing out that existing frameworks relied on no-IRIW and it is pretty hard to program to IRIW-reordering archs, they eventually guaranteed it (giving us so-called x86-TSO model).

Comment: That is true, being a TSO. But it is my understanding is that Intel (still?) does not officially claim that it _is_ a real TSO,. It just seems to behave that way.

Comment: They document it as being TSO (although not using that exact term) for the last several years in their guides (since the furor over the existing model being ill defined): _Any two stores are seen in a consistent order by processors other than those performing the stores_ (Section 8.2.2). They also then in 8.2.3.7 give the exact canonical IRIW example with the guarantee that the IRs see the IWs in consistent order. The example is more or less the OP's code. @LWimsey

Comment: Interesting, they do now..thanks for the referenes, have some reading to do.

Comment: About the last part of your answer, PowerPC uses only `lwsync` and `isync` for acquire/release. Doesn't the prevention of IRIW reordering require a full `sync` ?  (I do not have access to a PowerPC, everything I know is from Godbolt)

Comment: @LWimsey - I admit to not being up to date on PowerPC sync ops as I haven't looked at them since forever. Still what you say makes sense: IRIW is _allowed_ by acq/rel, so perhaps PowerPC is an example of a real case were acq/rel will result in out-of-order IRIW.

Comment: I was thinking about a scenario whereby an atomic RMW uses `memory_order_acq_rel` ordering.
One would expect that no memory operations should be re-ordered in both directions (ie. being both an acquire and release) and as such, you might argue that it acts as a full barrier that prevents all types of reordering (incl. #SL).

Comment: ... But using the RMW in an IRIW context, could show that it is not seq/cst since PowerPC uses `lwsync/isync` for acq_rel and `sync/isync` for seq_cst.
It might be an example that a full barrier is not necessarily seq_cst.
But I am not sure since the PowerPC documentation I found claims that `lwsync` cannot prevent #SL.. I asked Jeff Preshing this question and all he said was: "it's a hard question"

Comment: @LWimsey - yes, I think it is an example of a "full barrier" not necessarily being seq cst, and it's exactly the thing I was talking about above: just discussing the possible reorderings, e.g,. `LoadLoad`, `LoadStore` and fiends is _not_ enough to define a hardware memory model, because those are all local effects: it doesn't talk about how stores from _different_ CPUs must be ordered. Obviously two independent stores from different CPUs have no particular relationship, but once they have been _observed_ in some order the question becomes whether that implies ...

Comment: ... something about the order observed by other CPUs. How this works _isn't_ implied by just describing which of the 4 classic reordering combinations are allowed: you could even have a CPU with zero allowed reodering, but where different CPUs don't see the global write stream in the same order, without the need to invoke any local reordering at all. So SPARC (which, AFAIK) introduced the `#LoadStore` type notation for barriers) and x86 both have a "total store order" to answer that question, but both considered other models at some point and took a while to get there.

Comment: Other vendors, probably including PPC based on your example, might not have a TSO model, so then the question becomes more complicated and there are probably barriers that have non-local effects in order force a global order in cases where it is needed.

Comment: Software memory models, on the other hand, mostly sidestep this whole question by not really basing their formal language on "possible reoderings" or "barriers" but with a more abstract model with happens before and "total order of writes" and seq cst, etc. The difference between `seq_cst` and "almost" `seq_cst` stuff like your `mo_acq_rel` example probably reflects differences in real hardware though: we know the vendors all made sure it would mostly be fast on their hardware (witness the messy `consume` ordering, for example).